# Running apps in jailbroken phone

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

This may be a simple and stupid question, but I'm new to developing for apple so sorry for that. Will my app built with newest xcode is going to run the same on jailbroken phones and normal ones? Are there any things i should know to be able to develop an app for both normal and jailbroken iphones?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, the apps will run.  The question is how you're planning to get them onto the jailbroken handsets.  While (for now) apple allows jailbroken phones to get apps from the app store, they explicitly stated in the past that they may remove this ability.

Comment: Do you have a source for that 'explicit' statement, Aleks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you codesign apps with your provision profile they will run on jailbroken devices.

By the way, IAP and Game Center don't work clearly on these devices in sandbox mode (this doesn't affect distributed builds in Appstore).

Comment: Sandbox mode works fine, just have to uninstall AppSync package from Cydia.

Comment: Kreiri, thanks for tip. I didn't know the reason.